# rworldmap package - Warning if the number of quantiles was reduced

Tags: r, rworldmap

I am using this R code:

```
library(rworldmap)
Data <- read.table("D:/Bla/Maps/Test.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(Data, joinCode = "ISO3",nameJoinColumn = "ISO3CountryCode")
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot = "Data")
```

This produces a map but I get:

You asked for 7 quantiles, only 1 could be created in quantiles classification

I googled and it pointed me to [this code](http://code.google.com/p/rworld/source/browse/branches/andy/aug09/rworldmap/R/rwmGetClassBreaks.R?spec=svn46&r=46)

Not sure whether it is relevant.

This is the data I have used:

```
ISO3CountryCode Data
JPN 7
AUS 6
IND 6
CHN 5
GBR 5
CHE 4
IRN 4
DEU 3
EGY 3
ESP 3
LBY 3
TUN 3
USA 3
ARG 2
AUT 2
BRA 2
EST 2
GRC 2
ITA 2
TUR 2
URY 2
CHL 1
ETH 1
FRA 1
JOR 1
KEN 1
KOR 1
LTU 1
MEX 1
NLD 1
NZL 1
PER 1
POL 1
SAU 1
SRB 1
SVK 1
SVN 1
TZA 1
ZAF 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like by default `mapCountryData()` tries to fit data to quantiles for binning.  You'll need to help it along a little by tweaking the `catMethod` parameter.

I'm not sure what your values 1 through 7 mean.  If they are categories (and you want them all explicitly displayed in the legend), try:

```
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot = "Data", catMethod="categorical")
```

If you want to treat all values equally on a continuous scale, try:

```
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot = "Data", catMethod="fixedWidth")
```

If neither of these does do what you want, you might try altering `numCats` and/or `catMethod` see `?mapCountryData` for the possible values and their meaning.

Comment: Excellent - Thanks! The values represent a continuous scale so I opted for: mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot = "Data", catMethod="fixedWidth")